# configure id sequence hibernate generator

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Can I configure Hibernate not to do the select seq.nextval from dual as separate call before the actual insert ?

```
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) 
org.hibernate.SQL select SEQUENCE_1.nextval from dual 
org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator auditor50 - Sequence identifier generated: 122797 
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher auditor50 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1) 

<class..>
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="long">
       <generator class="sequence">
          <param name="sequence">SEQUENCE_1</param>
       </generator>
    </id>      
</class>
```

Comment: How would it get the value to insert then?

Comment: insert into table (ID) VALUES (SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL);

Comment: I'm not sure if this would stop the current behavior, but what if in the database the default value was `SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. But I don't know what difference it would make. If you want to do this for performance reasons:

1. Have you measured a significant difference between both approaches?
2. Do you know that the sequence ID generator of Hibernate is in fact a hilo sequence ID generator, and that it only gets the next value every N inserts (N defaulting at 50, IIRC), making it certainly faster than you might think?

Comment: 1. I haven't really measured it, but I insert 200+ rows per transaction

Comment: 2.For me it does every insert not every 50 inserts

Comment: 2. My mistake. When configured via annotations, the sequence generator is in fact the seqhilo generator. With XML, you have to use class="seqhilo" rather than class="sequence"